# How to change the color of label when input next to it is focused?

Tags: html, css, focus

I have a div with a label and an input-field within a form.

When the input-filed is focused I want the border of the div to change color (I managed to do that) but I also want the color of the label to change.
Since the label is not the input's parent I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="floating-fake">
  <label class="label-ff col-form-label-sm">Ansprechpartner</label>
  <input type="text" class="input-ff form-control-sm" name="ansprechpartner" value="{{ old('ansprechpartner') }}">
</div>
```

and here's the css:

```
.input-ff {
   width: 97%;
   margin-left: 3%;
   border: none;
   letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.input-ff:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: teal;
  background: #fff;
}
.floating-fake:focus-within {
  border-color: #22c7dd;
}
```

The label should change to `color: #22c7dd;`.
I have searched for this but only came across javascript solutions(which I'm trying to avoid) or other ones with the `+` selector that won't help me in this case.

I hope someone can help me with this since I'm not much experienced when it comes to html/css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage `:focus-within` and the descendant selector to change the color of label when input in the div is focused.

```css
.input-ff {
  width: 97%;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.input-ff:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: teal;
  background: #fff;
}

.floating-fake:focus-within {
  border-color: #22c7dd;
}

.floating-fake:focus-within label {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-fake">

  <label class="label-ff col-form-label-sm">Ansprechpartner</label>

  <input type="text" class="input-ff form-control-sm" name="ansprechpartner" value="red">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, I don't know why i didn't thought of this, it was too simple :D

Answer (score -1):

may you try this:

```
<div class="floating-fake">
  <label class="label-ff col-form-label-sm">Ansprechpartner</label>
  <input type="text" class="input-ff form-control-sm" name="ansprechpartner" value="{{ old('ansprechpartner') }}" onfocus="this.style.border-color='#22c7dd';">
</div>
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting on this post. The code is now visible.